# Apply border radius to inner view(progress bar) when applying padding to <Progress.Bar />

Tags: react-native

**Que** : How to apply border raduis to inner view of react-native-progress

**Version**

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
```

**Expected output**
[image: Screenshot]

**Current behaviour**
[image: current_output]

**Code**

```
<Progress.Bar
  color={'rgb(128,0,128)'}
  progress={0.5}
  borderWidth={1}
  borderColor={'rgba(128,0,128,0.2)'}
  unfilledColor={'white'}
  height={10}
  borderRadius={7.5}
  width={200}
  style={{ padding: 2, }}
/>
```

So after applying style with padding 2 I'll get the space for inner view
but when I try below code it wont work for me

`style={{ padding: 2,borderRadius:10 }}`

**So how apply border radius for inner view as per expected output**

Comment: Could you share edit code here? I am getting same issue. @Hardik Desai

Comment: Okay allow me some time Try to share edited repo @Miteshjadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that applying `border-radius` to inner `Animated.View` is not allowed as per props exposed by the [bar](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress/blob/master/Bar.js)  component. A suggestion would be that you can clone and modify the code and include `border-radius` in [progressStyle](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress/blob/master/Bar.js#L142) which can be derived from `props` like `color` for `backgroundColor` or can have some value by default.

Comment: thank you for input ;) Have to modify the inner file of library now.